# Ошибка при подключении intel mkl в visual studio

Tags: c++

Давно вожусь, не получается подключить intel mkl, для произведения матриц.
Вечно всякие ошибки.

1. Скачал с оф. сайта oneApi.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. Выбрал mkl и установил.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. Подключил библиотеку mkl.h.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
4. Выбрал в свойствах проекта parallel
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
5. Получаю ошибку.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что мне делать? Пробовал переустановить, не помогает.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, необходимо подключить сам dll файл:

```
#pragma comment( lib, "libname.lib" ) //вместо libname.lib ставите вашу библиотеку
```

Также, можно попробовать "поиграться" с функцией LoadLibrary.

Еще могу посоветовать [эту статью](https://ravesli.com/podklyuchenie-i-ispolzovanie-bibliotek-v-visual-studio-2017/).
Заранее извиняюсь, если мой ответ Вам не помог, ибо писать комментарии под вопросом не могу из-за низкой репутации :(
Удачи Вам!